# recursive function behaviour

Tags: c, function, recursion

#### program 1:

unable to print nothing, even we passed **string s**.

```
void reverse(char *s)
{
    if(*s)
    {
        return reverse(s+1); 
        printf("%c",*s);
    }
}
```

#### program 2:

works as exact behaviour, it printing the string in reverse order.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
    if(*str)
    {
        reverse(str+1);
        printf("%c", *str);
    }
}
```

could anybody know ,what would be the problem for program 1.
I think, in recursive function, we should put **return** statement before the function. is it must to put the return statement/necessary??.

Comment: In your first program you are returning before you print.

Comment: This is called "Unreachable code". Every modern compiler gives warning on such code.

Comment: In addition to the unreachable code, your function is declared with a `void` return, so it can't return a value anyway.

Comment: Do you understand that printing a value and returning a value from a function are two entirely different things?

Comment: I think the question is more: do you understand that a `return` statement immediately exits the function at that point?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with recursion. The printf statement is dead code and won't work for the same reason as

```
int main()
{
  return 0;
  printf("hello, world");
}
```

doesn't work. You should get compiler warnings for such code.

Furthermore, your recursive function needs a condition where it stops calling itself, or it will just endlessly spawn new functions until you get a stack overflow.

Comment: It has such a condition: `if(*str)...`, so it stops when it reaches the string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

In the first program there is return statement that exits the function without printing anything. That is the function calls itself recursively and in each recursion it returns control at once to the caller. The comtrol never achieves the print statement.

In fact the function can be rewritten like

```
void reverse(char *s)
{
    if(*s)
    {
        return reverse(s+1); 
    }
}
```